# Why to invalidate a session in a security filter, CSRF token is not updated

Tags: spring, spring-security

In a Spring Security application, a user is making a **GET** call to a private **/secure** url with **activated csrf**.
The user sends a credential cookie and then the user is authenticated and **JSESSIONID** is generated.

In the same browser becomes to make a **GET** call to **/secure**, with the **JSESSIONID** cookie and a credential cookie by another user.

In this case an owner security filter produces a change of user, invalid session of the first user, generate a
new session and authenticates the new credential.

This works until the new authenticated user sends a **POST** with the new **JSESSIONID**, but the **CSRF** token is getting to the old.

**CsrfFilter** is before my authentication filter, and **CsrfAuthenticationStrategy** not regenerate the **CSRF** token.

What is the right way to invalidate a session and the token csrf be updated?

Comment: I tried to get into the new session attribute csrf, but I think it is not the best solution. In this case CsrfAuthenticationStrategy regenerates the token csrf.

Answer (score 0):

The invalidation of session in spring security is automatic once you relogin as new user using the old JSESSION ID.

Basically you just have to bind the token generated on the new session generated by the authentication filter.

Try this solution, another filter after authentication

https://github.com/aditzel/spring-security-csrf-filter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/allanditzel/springframework/security/web/csrf/CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter.java

Same issue reported via this thread,

https://github.com/aditzel/spring-security-csrf-token-interceptor/issues/1

Comment: Thanks Vani,
The solution seems a bit intrusive, CsrfFilter uses CsrfTokenRepository, and implementation can rename the parameters and the head of csrf.
In my case I have csrf token, the problem is that the first user CSRF token arrives, and CSRF token is not regenerated.

Comment: It is not that intrusive really. Spring security filters are meant to be customized for your scenario

Answer (score -1):

I created a **HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository** bean type, which is the default implementation of **CsrfTokenRepository**, and use both to configure spring security repository csrf as my filter, so the two sites use the same bean.

**Config Bean**

```
@Bean
public void CsrfTokenRepository dafaultCsrfTokenRepository() {
   return new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
}
```

**Spring Security**

```
@Autowired
private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository;

private static HttpSecurity addCSRF(HttpSecurity http, CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository) throws Exception {
     http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository);
     return http;
}
```

**Invalidate session in filter**

```
private void invalidateCurrentSession(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        CsrfToken csrfToken=csrfTokenRepository.loadToken(request);
        session.invalidate();
        request.getSession();
        csrfTokenRepository.saveToken(csrfToken, request, response);
    }
}
```

If someone wanted to override the default behavior, you could define a bean that implements **CsrfTokenRepository** as **@Primary**